# NetBeans GUI editor, can't construct the object

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, balloon-tip

Its hard to explain it for me and even harder in english...
I have this *component* constructor

```
Balonik = new BalloonTip(textfield, new JLabel("Do not devide by 0!"),
            new RoundedBalloonStyle(5,5,Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK), 
            BalloonTip.Orientation.RIGHT_BELOW, 
            BalloonTip.AttachLocation.ALIGNED, 
            15, 
            15, 
            false
    );
```

and I put this code in *frame* constructor in netbeans jFrame project

```
public oknoo() {

    initComponents();

    Balonik = new BalloonTip(textfield, new JLabel("Do not devide by 0!"),
            new RoundedBalloonStyle(5,5,Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK), 
            BalloonTip.Orientation.RIGHT_BELOW, 
            BalloonTip.AttachLocation.ALIGNED, 
            15, 
            15, 
            false
    );
}
```

it is compiling however the BalloonTip doesnt show up.

The funny thing is that when Ive exported project to eclipse(where I could edit the initComponent() function), and left this *component* constructor in initComponent() function then it has worked. 
so the same code works in initComponent() function and not working within the constructor....

I dont understand. And Im asking because I cant just fix this problem in Eclipse and export back to netBeans.... because of this ...

```
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
```

Comment: Does not make sense. Provide compilable code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Have you initialised the textfield? Consider providing a fully runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: I hope now is clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BalloonTip` does not show up because it is created after `pack()` is called.
You will need to call `pack()` on the constructor after `initComponents()`,
not on that method.

```
public oknoo() {

    initComponents();

    Balonik = new BalloonTip(textfield, new JLabel("Do not devide by 0!"),
            new RoundedBalloonStyle(5,5,Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK), 
            BalloonTip.Orientation.RIGHT_BELOW, 
            BalloonTip.AttachLocation.ALIGNED, 
            15, 
            15, 
            false
    );

    pack();
}
```

But `pack()` should not be called on `initComponents()`. On **Code** properties of `JFrame` (right click on frame on GUI builder -> properties), select **No Resize Code** for **Form Size Policy**.

Comment: I would never discover this by my own... especially this:

In Code properties of JFrame (right click on frame on GUI builder -> properties), select No Resize Code for Form Size Policy.

THANKS

Comment: I suspected of the `pack()` method. Then I have made some tests editing the frame class outside NetBeans. So I look on frame properties to see what could be done on NetBeans to take `pack()` off the `initComponents` method.